# Is there any way to send an in Org Notification to authorized User, when Opportunity Record has Updated

Tags: trigger, notification, push, push-notification

Hello I'm trying to write a trigger when any fields of Opportunity__c (It is Custom in our Org) has updated ,

check the User's object Permission and Send relevant user for in org Notification
Like : ( Opportunity Stage 'Prospect' has changed to 'Closed Won' )

i heard it is possible only when chatter mention has added to user. this could be possible?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using Platform Event. Platform events are the event messages (or notifications) that your apps send and receive to take further action. Platform events simplify the process of communicating changes and responding to them without writing complex logic. Publishers and subscribers communicate with each other through events. One or more subscribers can listen to the same event and carry out actions.

There is a trailhead module which you can refer for step by step guide.

[Build an Instant Notification App](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/workshop-platform-events/platform-event-define)